# WKWebView invalidaccesserror dom exception 15 a parameter or operation is not supported by underlying object

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift, wkwebview

So we have this screwed-up app architecture where we are opening a few pages in WKWebView. 
Now on tap of HTML buttons we are posting messages to native code using:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.didTapOnButton.postMessage(messageToPost);
```

It works fine in a lot of cases but sometimes it fails giving the InvalidAccessError DOM Exception 15. This error is usually caused by CORS issues on web browsers, but any idea what could be causing it on WKWebView and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. One of my custom script was getting added on a third-party web page which was causing this issue.